# How can i create movieclip from png what is imported to a array?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, png, sprite, movieclip

i would import jpg files from the library and put them into an array. after this i would place them on the stage and apply event listener on them.
or how can i add event listener to the array?
 sry for my english. thank u for help

```
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import com.bitmap.InteractivePNG;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    var polc1Ar:Array = new Array();
    inditasFu();

    function inditasFu(){
        behivas();
        rakdkiFu();
    }

    function behivas(){
        for (var i=1; i!=3; i++) {
            var ClassRef:Class = getDefinitionByName("elsok" + i.toString()) as Class;
            var classRef = new ClassRef();
            classref.alphaTolerance = 255;
            classref.smoothing = true;  
            classref.pixelSnapping = "never"; 
            polc1Ar.push(classRef)
            }
    }
    function rakdkiFu (){

        for (var i=0; i!=polc1Ar.length; i++){
            var monci:Sprite= new Sprite;
            monci=polc1Ar[i];
            monci.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownFu);
            monci.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpFu);
        }
    }

    function mouseDownFu(e:MouseEvent):void{
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
        mc.startDrag(false);
        mc.alpha = .55;
        this.addChild(mc);
    }
    function mouseUpFu(e:MouseEvent):void{  
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
        mc.stopDrag();
        mc.alpha = 1;  

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`monci=polc1Ar[i];` You are assigning a bitmap there to a Sprite. Instead, create a new Sprite, add the bitmap to it with addChild and manipulate the sprite instances instead of the bitmaps. Anyway you will need an InteractiveObject instance for the mouse events and Bitmap is not one.

Comment: can u show me how can i add this to child for sprite?
monci.addchild(polc1ar[i]); ?? is will be usable? im rly newby and i started learn actionscript at home about 2 week ago. i couldnt find good tutorial for the beginners.

Comment: Exactly like that, but with capital C - monci.addChild(polc1ar[i]);